# How to handle graceful SIGINT shutdown with ts-node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I'm trying to gracefully handle shutdown of a Twitch bot from a ctrl+c SIGINT. I'm using the bot template [here](https://github.com/BarryCarlyon/twitch_misc/tree/main/chat/eventbased_space).

I define a process.on('SIGINT') handler as so,

```js
process.on( 'SIGINT', () => {
    console.log("\nGracefully shutting down from SIGINT (Ctrl-C)");
    fs.writeFile('./commands.json', JSON.stringify(commands, null, 2), (error) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`error encountered when saving commands.json: ${error}`)
            process.exit()
        }
        console.log('commands.json successfully written')
        process.exit();
    })
})
```

Running this as a .js file under node works fine,

```bash
node ./chat_bot.js
...
Gracefully shutting down from SIGINT (Ctrl-C)
commands.json successfully written
PS C:\ProjectDir>
```

but as a .ts file using ts-node,

```bash
npx ts-node --esm ./chat_bot.ts
...
Gracefully shutting down from SIGINT (Ctrl-C)
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
y // the same behavior occurs with n or a second ctrl-c
PS C:\ProjectDir>
```

it terminates before it can write any data, but is still entering the proc.on handler.

I've checked that the proc.on handler is identical in `chat_bot.ts` and `chat_bot.js`. The same issue also occurs using `writeFileSync` instead of `writeFile`.

I did find [this](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/457) now-closed ts-node issue claiming to have solved the issue in ts-node v4.0.0, but nothing there proved to be helpful.

tsconfig.json and versions:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module":"node16",
        "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
        "noEmit": true,
    },
    
}
```

- ts-node v10.9.1
- typescript v5.0.4
- node v19.4.0

EDIT:

Rewriting a minimum reproducible example as requested by @jsejcksn, I've found that the problem only occurs when importing the ChatBot class from a separate file. I'm not sure how best to include the code here so I'll put them in hastebin links for now, [stack_mre.ts](https://hastebin.skyra.pw/yovodivoko.ts) and [stack_mre_bot.ts](https://hastebin.skyra.pw/jojiquzoho.kotlin) (the imported file).

I think this may have something to do with ts-node failing to handle forwarding signals to child processes as I've seen issues relating to that on github, but again all the ones I've seen are already closed.

Comment: Based on that message, it looks like ts-node is running a bat file, not "the actual thing", and your ctrl-c gets trapped by that.

Comment: Please update the question with a [mre].